# JSON, Jackson and multiline string

Tags: json, string, jackson

I have the following JSON.

```
{ "content" : "value" }
```

I have Jackson constructing the JSON string.

If the value is a multiline text, example:

```
A
B
C
```

What I see is: `{ "content" : "A\r\nB\r\nC" }`

It explicitly sets `\r\n` (CRLF) for every line.

I am wondering if I can configure Jackson to output this:

```
{ "content" : "A
B
C" }
```

Which is; A, B and C are rendered as 3 lines and not in 1 line as "A\r\nB\r\nC".

Comment: My question is: Can't Jackson set them as newlines than explicitly setting \r\n for newline?

Comment: Jackson does not change the string content unless you set up custom serialization. If the Java variable has \r\n, that's what you get. If you want a normalization, you'll need custom serialization.

Comment: Jackson is not changing it. What it does is convert A, B and C in 3 lines to a single line separated by \r\n explicitly. When I converted the JSON string back to Java object, and printed A, B and C, they got printed in 3 lines. My question is that if the same String needs to be parsed by a different client, do I have to document about escaping \r\n in the JSON string constructed by Jackson?

Comment: No, it doesn't. There is no such thing as one line with \r\n. \r\n is the thing that makes something more than one line.

Comment: "I can configure Jackson to output this" — but that isn't JSON. You can't have literal new lines in a JSON string.

Comment: @serverfaces - "My question is that if the same String needs to be parsed by a different client, do I have to document about escaping \r\n in the JSON string constructed by Jackson?" -- the answer to this question is no: \r and \n are part of the JSON standard and should be understood by any JSON parser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Json object contains new line character converted to "\n" while converting json object to string or byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771911/json-object-contains-new-line-character-converted-to-n-while-converting-json)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you wonder why Jackson escapes linefeeds. If so, the answer can be found right [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt).

Comment: Sorry for poor question. I would like to change linefeed character with something else. For example a unicode character and with I would to display it multiline in browser with CSS tricks.

Comment: It is possible to register a `CharacterEscapes` (see http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator.html#setCharacterEscapes(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.CharacterEscapes)) which allows escaping using other mechanisms.