# Json object contains new line character converted to "\n" while converting json object to string or byte

Tags: java, json

Json object containing new line character gets converted to `"\n"` while converting json object to string or byte. If I choose any one of the below way it is converting new line character to `\n`.

```
byte[] json = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(jsonObject);
 String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonObject);
 objectMapper.writeValue(json, jsonElection);
```

Example:

```
Brown 
And
Ken
```

Above data got changed as

```
Brown\nAnd\nKen
```

Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Question is that \n is not expected for the functionality that @Nagendra is intending.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON, Jackson and multiline string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482795/json-jackson-and-multiline-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the intended working. Newline characters are escaped to the `"\n"` character sequence.

Your output is perfectly fine and it means the 3 words `"Brown"`, `"And"` and `"Ken"` separated by newline characters. When you decode it you will have the exact same text (as your input).

You asked for json text and that is what you got. If a json value contains a newline character, it is represented by the character sequence `"\n"`.