# How to configure Jackson to not handle line breaks in Spring boot project?

Tags: java, jackson, line-breaks

Body: I'm using Jackson to serialize Java objects to JSON strings. However, I don't want Jackson to escape line breaks in the JSON strings. How can I configure Jackson to not handle line breaks?

Here's an example of the Java code I'm using:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

public class MyObject {
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create an object
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        myObject.setMessage("Hello,\nWorld!");

        // Create an ObjectMapper object
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

        // Convert the object to a JSON string
        String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);

        // Output the JSON string
        System.out.println(jsonString);
    }
}
```

When I run this code, the output is:

```
{"message":"Hello,\nWorld!"}
```

break line change to String
However, I want the output to be:

```
{"message":"Hello,
World!"}
```

Hello and World are in different line
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Json object contains new line character converted to "\n" while converting json object to string or byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771911/json-object-contains-new-line-character-converted-to-n-while-converting-json)